# Unable to add a break line to a string coming from a label in lwc

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, customlabel

I have created a custom label and fetching it in lwc. Below is the code snippet
Javascript :

```
@track labelMessage;
connectedCallback() {
this.labelMessage = this.label.message.replace('breakLine', '<br>');
}
```

HTML

```
<span>{labelMessage}</span>
```

Output :

```
My Name is <br> Sam.
```

The breakLine word is replaced by '<br>' but I am expecting it to show the string after 
 in the next line

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Option 1: `lightning-formatted-text`

You don't need to replace the newlines with HTML line breaks; this component does it for you!

Option 2: `lightning-formatted-rich-text`

You can put the value into this component to preserve custom HTML; it will sanitize the input for scripts and other blacklisted HTML elements.

Option 3: CSS

You can control whitespace in CSS:

```
<span style="white-space: pre-line">{labelMessage}</span>
```

Do not replace the line break with an HTML line break.

Option 4: `innerHTML`

```
<span lwc:ref="label" lwc:dom="manual"></span>
```

```
renderedCallback() {
  this.refs.label.innerHTML = this.label.message.replace('breakLine', '<br>');
}
```

Note that this option requires that you do this in `renderedCallback`, because the element won't exist before then.

Comment: On option 4, should this not be `lwc:dom="manual"` to avoid unexpected behaviour from the compiled LWC?

Comment: @PhilW It's not strictly necessary since this component will never see a render cycle after the first time, but I'd agree it's a best practice to mark any element you intend to modify directly later.

Answer (score 1):

The best option would be to just use a `lightning-formatted-rich-text`

```
 <lightning-formatted-rich-text value={customLabelWithBreak}></lightning-formatted-rich-text>
```

JS:

```
import LabelWithBreak from '@salesforce/label/c.LabelWithBreak';

connectedCallback() {
    this.customLabelWithBreak = LabelWithBreak;
}
```

Label :

```
<labels>
    <fullName>LabelWithBreak</fullName>
    <language>en_US</language>
    <protected>false</protected>
    <shortDescription>LabelWithBreak</shortDescription>
    <value>Hi <br> this is me</value>
</labels>
```

[image]